# How to get the first letter after every hyphen and concat it to a new column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, substring

In Mysql DB, i've a column in which data are like in example. Now I need to get the first letter and the letters after the hyphen. There is no standard length of that string.

Example:

row1: asdaff-asarger-adsf-tggdg

result: aaat

row2: jbkjn-kjnsd-jnskn-kkjngk-kndskjn-irfjk

result: jkjkki

I tried substring but its not helping

Comment: Use REGEXP_REPLACE().

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION extractWords(str TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE wordList TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE word VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

    SET maxIdx = CHAR_LENGTH(str);

    WHILE idx <= maxIdx DO
        SET currChar = SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]';

        IF currChar THEN
            SET word = CONCAT(word, SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1));
        ELSE
            IF prevChar THEN
                IF LENGTH(word) > 0 THEN
                    SET wordList = CONCAT(wordList, SUBSTRING(word, 1, 1));
                    SET word = '';
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        SET prevChar = currChar;
        SET idx = idx + 1;
    END WHILE;

    IF LENGTH(word) > 0 THEN
        SET wordList = CONCAT(wordList, SUBSTRING(word, 1, 1));
    END IF;

    RETURN TRIM(wordList);
END;
```

[check the example](https://dbfiddle.uk/eptjmzXu)